# Почему в условии цикла false?

Tags: javascript

При проверке на дебагере оказывается, что доходя до условия цикла `while`, возникает `false` и цикл просто игнорируется. Не понимаю, почему `false`?

```
function askPassword(question) {
  const ask = +prompt('Введите новый пароль, не менее трех символов');
  let password = ask;
  while ( password.lenght < 3 ) {
    password = +prompt('Пароль не подходит, введите другой');
  }
  
  return password;
}

let newPassword = askPassword();
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145753/discussion-on-question-by-artem-----false); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

1. опечатка в названии свойства `lenght` - правильно `length`
2. `password` - это число, а у числа нет ни свойства `lenght`, ни `length`

Если нужно получить строку, не нужно использовать унарный плюс, для преобразования в число.